Complete market price and incomplete market price specification
We know that if a liquid market of an asset exists, then the standard derivative pricing theorem implies an equivalent martingale measure exists, not necessarily unique, under which the discounted relative price process, for all tradeable assets, are martingales. Assume that the incompleteness of the market comes from an unhedeable part embedded in the payoff function associated with a tradeable asset that is linked to insurance risk. For simplicity, assume that there is a 2-dimensional Brownian motion $(B_t , W_t)$, where the processes $B_t$ and $W_t$ derive hedgeable and unhedgeable processes, respectively.
Applying the Dol´eans-Dade exponential, the Radon-Nicodym density is of the following form:
\begin{equation}
\frac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\mathbb{P}} = \mathcal{E}\left(\int_{0}^{T} \eta_s dW_s \right) = \exp\left\{ \int_{0}^{T}\phi_s dB_s -\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{T}\phi_s^2 ds + \int_{0}^{T}\eta_s dW_s - \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{T}\eta_s^2 ds  \right\}
\end{equation}
where $\phi_s$ is the complete market price corresponding to the hedgeable random factor $B_t$, and $\eta_t$ is the incomplete market price corresponding to the unhedgeable random factor $W_t$.
Now, suppose that our contract has a payoff function $F(L_T)$, where $F(.)$ is a real function and $L_T$ is the loss process of the insured over a period time $[0, T]$. For example,
\begin{equation}
Payoff = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
C & if\; L_T < D\\
pC & if\; L_T\ge D
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}
where $p\in(0, 1), C, D$ are pre-known values and $L_T = \sum_{i=1}^{N(T)}Y_i$ models the aggregate claim process obeying a compound Poisson Process, let's say. Given that the risk-free interest rate follows a CIR model, I wonder what the complete and incomplete market prices of $\phi_s$ and $\eta_s$ look like? How can we specify a parametric form for them?
